# how to calculate this limit: $\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sin{\frac{2\pi}{i}} $

Tags: calculus

how to calculate this limit:
$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sin{\frac{2\pi}{i}}$

someone said that: $\displaystyle \sin \frac{2\pi}{i}=\frac{2\pi}{i}$, why?

Please help, thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Note that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sin{\frac{2\pi}{n}} = n \sin{\frac{2\pi}{n}}$.

Comment: The small angle approximation says that for $x$ close to $0$, $\sin x \approx x$. More precisely, $\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{\sin x}{x}} = 1$.

Comment: [They should have said](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis) $\sin\tfrac{2\pi}{n}\sim\tfrac{2\pi}{n}$.

Comment: Are you sure the question is really what you wrote? There is no mention of the index $i$ in the summands?

Comment: $\sum_i\sin\frac{2\pi}i$ diverges like the harmonic series.

Comment: @Ben I think you want to intend $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin{\frac{2\pi}{k}}$, or not?

Comment: @Clement C. yes, just now modified that mistake. thanks

Comment: @Pawel yes, correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin{\Big(\frac{2\pi}{k}\Big)}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sin{\Big(\frac{2\pi}{k}\Big)}?$$

Since $$\sin{\frac{2\pi}{k}} \sim \frac{2\pi}{k}\text{ , in fact} \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{\sin{\frac{2\pi}{k}}}{\frac{2\pi}{k}}=1$$
so
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2\pi}{k}\text{diverges}\implies  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sin{\Big(\frac{2\pi}{k}\Big)} \text{ diverges from the limit comparison test}$$

Comment: Write $\sin \left( {\frac{{2\pi }}{k}} \right)$ instead of $\frac{{\sin (2\pi )}}{k}$ and $\sin \frac{{(2\pi )}}{k}$.

Comment: Ok thanks I agree! I will edit my answer!

Comment: This is not the question which was asked... it's worth checking with the OP if you suspect they made a mistake in their question, before answering.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^n a = na$.

Comment: @pawel thanks but what is the answer?

Comment: @Ben The answer is that the limit of you sum is the series above and in particular you have to consider the series above that it is divergent! The reason why someone said $a_k=\sin{\frac{2\pi}{k}}$ is $b_k=\frac{2\pi}{k}$ is referred to the fact that  $a_k$ is asympthotically equal to $b_k$ in the sense that the limit of the ratio is 1...if this is not what you are interested in, I have not understand exactly what you want to know

Comment: @pawel thanks, have to look at harmonic series again

Comment: For $x\in[0;\frac{\pi}{2}]$  $\sin{x}>\frac{2x}{\pi}$ (it is easy to see on the graph), so  $\sin{\frac{2\pi}{k}}>\frac{2}{\pi}*\frac{2\pi}{k}=\frac{4}{k}$ for all $k>4$. The series do diverges.